# Trying to get the actual data that cause an exception

Tags: oracle, exception, plsql, associative-array

I have a procedure that takes an input of 2 Associative arrays and after some basic count checks, does a FORALL statement to insert the data into a table.

Here is the procedure:

```
    PROCEDURE   INSERT_RECS(P_PROD_TYP IN prod_type, P_PROD_ADD_PK IN prod_pk_type) 
        IS

        uniq_key EXCEPTION;
        PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(uniq_key, -00001);
        loc_cnt  NUMBER;

        BEGIN
            IF P_PROD_TYP.COUNT = P_PROD_ADD_PK.COUNT THEN
               FORALL i IN P_PROD_TYP.FIRST .. P_PROD_TYP.LAST
                INSERT INTO product_table ( pk, 
                                            id,
                                            created_by,
                                            created_on,
                                            last_chg_by, 
                                            last_chg_on)
                                    VALUES (P_PROD_ADD_PK(i),
                                            P_PROD_TYP(i).id,
                                            P_PROD_TYP(i).created_by,
                                            P_PROD_TYP(i).created_on,
                                            NULL,
                                            NULL);

            END IF;
        EXCEPTION
            WHEN uniq_key THEN
                loc_cnt := SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS.count;
                FOR i IN 1 .. loc_cnt LOOP
                    dbms_output.put_line('EXCEPTION: Array Index: ' || SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS(i).error_index ||
                            ' Message: ' || SQLERRM(-SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS(i).ERROR_CODE) || 
                            ' SQLERRM: ' || SQLERRM || 
                            ' SQLCODE: ' || SQLCODE ||    
                            ' stack: ' || SYS.dbms_utility.format_call_stack);
                END LOOP;    
                RETURN;
        END;
```

What I would like is if I hit an exception, is there a way that I could have view of the record that is causing the issue, essentially the index in the associative array or at least have the SQL% info have the info.

I have look at the following:
http://www.dba-oracle.com/plsql/t_plsql_exceptions.htm

but this outputs the info about the column but that is not what I am after.

Comment: Since you have the index (SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS(i).error_index ), why don't you just loop through p_prod_typ until you get to the index of the record that caused the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if really answers your query but you can use the loop variable i in exception block to display the content of the exception array in your case. See below an example procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PROC1 (V_EMP_ID DBMS_SQL.NUMBER_TABLE)
IS
     lv_error_string VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
    FORALL INDX IN V_EMP_ID.FIRST..V_EMP_ID.LAST SAVE EXCEPTIONS
    UPDATE EMPLOYEES 
     ---trying to rasie an exception by using a calculation
    SET SALARY=SALARY * 99999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999
    WHERE ID_E= V_EMP_ID(INDX);

EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS 
    THEN
    FOR i IN 1 .. SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS.COUNT
    LOOP
        ---Am printing the value of the exception array.
        dbms_output.put_line('exception Raised for record' ||V_EMP_ID(i));           

    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Ouput:

```
SQL> DECLARE
     empid   DBMS_SQL.NUMBER_TABLE;
    BEGIN
     empid (1) := 1;
     empid (2) := 9;

     PROC1 (empid);
   END;  

/
exception Raised for record  1

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: My understanding of the SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS and the rows that it contains are that they are just the exceptions, so there would not be a 1 to 1 relations to the rows in the table (V_EMP_ID) you are iterating through in the FORALL.  Is this not the case?

Essentially index i will most likely not equal index INDX

Comment: `SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS` is a implicit cursor which holds all the exception raised. And in the exception block we are just printing it. So FORALL loop runs seperately and the exception blocks implicit cursor loops seperately. That's what is showed in example. I am passing a collection of number and catching the exception in the exception block.

Comment: Yes, after doing more research I see that is the case, thank you very much.