# How does FOR i IN 1 .. SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS.COUNT point to the elements of the collection that threw the exceptions?

Tags: oracle, exception, plsql, bulkupdate

I have taken this code as an [example from this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43879447/trying-to-get-the-actual-data-that-cause-an-exception):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PROC1 (V_EMP_ID DBMS_SQL.NUMBER_TABLE)
IS
    lv_error_string VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
    FORALL INDX IN V_EMP_ID.FIRST..V_EMP_ID.LAST SAVE EXCEPTIONS
    UPDATE EMPLOYEES 
     ---trying to rasie an exception by using a calculation
    SET SALARY=SALARY * 999999999999
    WHERE ID_E= V_EMP_ID(INDX);

EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS 
    THEN
    FOR i IN 1 .. SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS.COUNT
    LOOP
        ---Am printing the value of the exception array.
        dbms_output.put_line('exception Raised for record' ||V_EMP_ID(i));           
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Can someone explain how `V_EMP_ID(i)` points to the actual elements that caused the exception since `i` is in `1 .. SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS.COUNT`. Shouldnt `V_EMP_ID(i)` always be pointing to the first element of the collection in the first iteration?

---

PS added the below on 12/17

In my code below I'm trying to emulate the `MERGE INTO` functionality without using `MERGE INTO` for some reason.

Using collections, I'm inserting records from a temp table to a main table. If that row exists in the main table, we will get a `DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX` sort of error and the error details get saved using `SAVE EXCEPTIONS`.
In the `EXCEPTION` block, I want to update all the main table rows that have errored out and update them with a set of values from the temp table.
Surprisingly, `FORALL i IN 1 .. SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS.COUNT` and `temp_data(i)`  updated the correct rows in the main table for me. I tried non-sequential rows too and it worked well. How is this possible?

```
declare
TYPE data_tbl IS TABLE OF EMPLOYEE_TEMP%rowtype INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
    temp_data data_tbl;
begin       
        select * bulk collect into temp_data from EMPLOYEE_TEMP
        where EVENT_OID='30047767_1' and USERID='SINISDI2';
    
   FORALL i IN 1 .. temp_data.COUNT SAVE EXCEPTIONS
       INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE D
        (D.VPD_KEY,
              D.OID,
              D.EVENT_OID,
              D.PID,
              D.AMOUNT,
              D.MIR,
              D.REPORTING,
              D.MODIFIED_BY_USER,
              D.MODIFIED_ON,
              D.VERSION,
              D.TYPE_OID,
              D.F_ELIGIBLE)
       VALUES ( temp_data(i).VPD_KEY,
              temp_data(i).OID,
              temp_data(i).EVENT_OID,
              temp_data(i).PID,
              temp_data(i).AMOUNT,
              temp_data(i).MIR,
              temp_data(i).REPORTING,
              temp_data(i).USERID,
              SYSDATE,
              0,
              temp_data(i).TYPE_OID,
              temp_data(i).F_ELIGIBLE
              );
  
   EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS
   THEN
      IF SQLCODE = -24381
      THEN
    FORALL i IN 1 .. SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS.COUNT 
   UPDATE EMPLOYEE D
     SET      D.AMOUNT=temp_data(i).AMOUNT,
              D.REPORTING=temp_data(i).REPORTING,
              D.MIR=temp_data(i).MIR,
              D.MODIFIED_BY_USER=temp_data(i).USERID,
              D.MODIFIED_ON = temp_data(i).MODIFIED_ON,
              D.VERSION = D.VERSION+1,
              D.F_ELIGIBLE = S.F_ELIGIBLE
       where D.PID = temp_data(i).PID AND D.TYPE_OID = temp_data(i).TYPE_OID;
      ELSE 
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQLERRM(SQLCODE)) ;
      END IF;     
end; 
/
```

Comment: You're right, that's not correct. Check out Code Listing 2 in this blog post for a very detailed example: https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/on-avoiding-termination

Comment: Short version, I think you should use `V_EMP_ID(sql%BULK_EXCEPTIONS(i).ERROR_INDEX)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quote from the capital [12.4.1.4 Handling FORALL Exceptions After FORALL Statement Completes](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-optimization-and-tuning.html#GUID-DAF46F06-EF3F-4B1A-A518-5238B80C69FA):

> SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS(i).ERROR_INDEX is the number of the DML statement that failed.

The number of the DML statement is equivalent to the element index in the collection.

Have a look at following working example:

```sql
create table tab (id, val check (val<=3)) as
    select rownum, rownum from dual connect by level<=3
/
declare 
    type idtab is table of int;
    ids idtab;
begin    
    select id bulk collect into ids
    from tab;
    
    declare
        forallexcp exception;
        pragma exception_init (forallexcp, -24381);
    begin
        forall i in 1..ids.count save exceptions
            update tab set val = val + 1
            where id = ids(i); 
    exception when forallexcp then
        dbms_output.put_line (
            sql%rowcount||' row(s) inserted ('||sql%bulk_exceptions.count||' with error).');    
        for i in 1..sql%bulk_exceptions.count loop dbms_output.put_line (
            'id='||ids(sql%bulk_exceptions(i).error_index)||' sqlerrm='||
            sqlerrm (-(sql%bulk_exceptions(i).error_code)));
        end loop;
    end;
end;
/
```

Result:

```
2 row(s) inserted (1 with error).
id=3 sqlerrm=ORA-02290: check constraint (.) violated
```

Comment: Thank you. This is my understanding too. But can you check my edit in the question?

Comment: I don't believe that the block in your last edit working correctly. Please take a look at this example on [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=9f5aabe4335649fb25c117b1bbe64068). I expected update of id=(2,3) instead of id=(2,4). Please change the db<>fiddle and post the link if you have another constellation of the data.