# [PLSQL]How to know the exact row which raise SAVE EXCEPTION in BULK COLLECT

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, bulk-collect

I'm trying to update rows from a bulk collect with limit using `forall` statement. However I couldn't get the exact row which raise the exception.

```
    -- Cursor which get the rows to update

    -- Creation of the table TAB_REQ

BEGIN

    OPEN  c_REQ;
   LOOP
      FETCH c_REQ BULK COLLECT INTO TAB_REQ LIMIT 50000;
   BEGIN

   FORALL ii in 1 .. TAB_REQ.count SAVE EXCEPTIONS
      
   -- Update statement where exception will be raise at id=164588

   EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS
      THEN
        l_errors := sql%BULK_EXCEPTIONS.count;
            FOR i IN 1 .. l_errors
            LOOP
               l_errno := sql%BULK_EXCEPTIONS(i).ERROR_CODE;
               l_msg := sqlerrm(-l_errno);
               l_idx := sql%BULK_EXCEPTIONS(i).ERROR_INDEX;
               DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_errno||' : '||l_msg||' - '||l_idx||', id_ext: '|| TAB_REQ(i).id_ext);
            END LOOP;
      END;
    exit when TAB_REQ.COUNT =0;
 END LOOP;
CLOSE c_REQ;
```

The result is that the id printed out in exception does not correspond to the id that raise error in update loop, and the number of rows updated has 50000 less, while is exactly the limit number in bulk collect.

Anyone knows the raison?

Comment: You are missing the code that shows what you are printing. 
Is this the same as [How does FOR i IN 1 .. SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS.COUNT point to the elements of the collection that threw the exceptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65331361/20324967)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `sql%bulk_exceptions`. You can see an example [here](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1422998100346727312). Keep in mind the errors are generic (meaning for errors such as "cannot insert null into X" you won't get the column name when using `sqlerrm`.).

To catch the errors you must define the exception before the execution block (or at the package level), then handle it:

```
DECLARE
    e_forall EXCEPTION;
    PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT (e_forall, -24381);
BEGIN
    ... bulk insert code that generates the exception ...

EXCEPTION 
    WHEN e_forall THEN
        FOR i IN 1 .. SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS.COUNT  
          LOOP  
             DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Error '  
                || ' on index '  
                || SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS(i).ERROR_INDEX  
                || SQLERRM (-1 * SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS(i).ERROR_CODE));  
          END LOOP;  


END;
/
```

What does the code generate on your side that prevents you from seeing the error/cause?

UPDATE:

OK, now that you updated the code + gave the output I think I found it.

The problem is here: `TAB_REQ(i).id_ext`

Try: `TAB_REQ(l_idx).id_ext`

`ERROR_INDEX` obtained from the array index is the actual record id, not the array index. So using i on the record will always return a wrong record. You need the index recovered from i.

Comment: Sorry i didn't put the part where I display the error, but I did use sql%bulk_exceptions, still no chance. Just updated the error display section in the post :)

Comment: OK, Normally, the error_index provided by the array index should be enough to identify the invalid input. Can you also show some printouts by dbms_output ? I don't see any reason for it to not display the correct records. So far everytime I used it, I had no issues identifying the invalid rows.

Comment: That's what I get as error:
```Traitement - Début - 07/12/2022 11:08:10
12899 : ORA-12899: valeur trop grande pour la colonne  (réelle : , maximum : ) - 48801, id_ext: 5973
Loop : 1
Loop : 2
Ligne MAJ : 82041
Traitement - Fin07/12/2022 11:08:49```
I update I string chain longer than it should be when id_ext = 164588 in my update, but in error output, they don't match. Also the number of rows updated has 5000 rows less than it should has

Comment: I updated the answer, please check if it fixes the problem and mark as Accepted if it does.

Comment: Great! It solves the problem, thanks! By the way, any idea on why it skip one loop?

Comment: It didn't go through all the rows in the bulk collect where I limite it 50000 per loop. In the end, the number of rows it went through has 50000 rows less the it should be. Is that because of there is an exception in one loop, so that all the rows in that loop won't be executed?

Comment: I think your condition is wrong. `FOR i IN a..b` already stops at the "edge". There is no reason to check if the count is 0. Furthermore, you exited outside the actual iterator. Instead of `exit when TAB_REQ.COUNT =0;` do `exit when c_req%notfound` .  Also, the limit is overkill. Instead of 50k, try `BULK COLLECT INTO TAB_REQ LIMIT 1000` . And even 1000 is a lot, believe it or not. The point of **BULK COLLECT** is not just speed. It's also memory management. Try with the new exit clause and the lower limit.